# VDI Guideline 2143 Sheet 1: Motion rules for cam mechanisms; theoretical fundamentals

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, linear-motion

Hello Motion Control Enthusiast, I am a motion control student, and looking for your suggestion for a **Free downloadable** English-translated version of **VDI Guideline 2143**, **theoretical fundaments of cam design** (the original copy is in German), or a book/blog/article that explains the **VDI Guidelines 2143** for the beginner.

In Europe, the VDI Guideline 2143, specifically Sheet 1, has been something of a "bible" for cam technicians. The German version can be downloaded from the VDI website which costs around 86 euros I just can't afford it.

Appreciate your suggestion and thank you very much.

Comment: From [on-topic](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): **Certain types of questions are never allowed, including:
Questions asking us to find or recommend a product, service or other external resource.** Sorry.

Comment: Ask your library.